# How to display a token collection on opensea before it is minted?

Tags: erc-721, nft, erc-1155, opensea, mint

Is there a way to display non-minted "yet" tokens on Opensea with the required msg.value as a price set directly by the contract?
So instead of me paying the gas of thousands of tokens, I want to display an unminted-yet version as a temporary representative of the actual token.

Answer (score 0):

No. There is not.

............

But there are efficient ways to mint lots of tokens.

In fact, the first ERC-721 contract is Su Squares // https://tenthousandsu.com

I created it specifically as a demonstration that it is possible to mint lots of tokens with a low per-item gas fee.

It is cited specifically in the ERC-721 paper for this purpose, and we minted 10,000 tokens at [an average of](https://etherscan.io/address/0xE9e3F9cfc1A64DFca53614a0182CFAD56c10624F) 190 gas each.

Comment: Apparently, some people can list their token representatives without minting the actual token and displaying the whole 10000 token collections from day one and letting people pick what they want to mint. Here's an example between minting something yourself and just listing a token representative that points to the actual token: https://bafkreih6mbs7ixohp6cbcgii33t4c73ct2i6o4xelm6a5s5wrdgjlac2ri.ipfs.dweb.link/

Comment: In case you want to check that example collection yourself: https://opensea.io/collection/onchainmask